# Did python dependency require to install gatsby-cli@4.24.0?

Tags: python, npm, gatsby, npm-install

I tried to install gatsbycli-4.24.0 but it asks for python dependency(asks for path node-gyp) in my windows machine. previously i used gatsbycli2.7.4, for vulnerabilities problem i tried to upgrade to 4.24.0.

```
Error: Could not find any Python installation to use
gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.fail (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-python.js:307:47)
gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.runChecks (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-python.js:136:21)
```

Did python installation required to install gatsbycli4.24.0? Also, please suggest the good version for gatsby to avoid major security vulnerabilities.

```
npm install gatsby-cli@4.24.0 -g
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Did python installation required to install gatsbycli4.24.0?

Yes it is, since there are some image processing modules ([Sharp for example](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-plugin-sharp/) which is pretty well-known) uses Python.

> Also, please suggest the good version for gatsby to avoid major
> security vulnerabilities.

Well, the obvious answer is to update to the latest stable which is the one you are pointing out, the [`4.24`](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/releases/tag/gatsby%404.24.0)

Comment: Thank you for the clearcut information :)